# Azure Gateway and JWT

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-web-app-service, load-balancing

**Current implementation:**

Single-instance WebApp with custom authentication (own DB) and custom server-based token management (matching session-token-user in an in-memory table).

**Desired implementation:**

Multiple WebApp instances behind Azure Application Gateway as a load balancer and URL router. Still with custom authentication. Token handling: ????? (preferably JWT)

As this will be a multi-tenant service, we don't want to use AD.

**Questions:**

What would be the best way to implement this scenario? Where we can keep track of users vs. tokens? This is, considering that now many servers need to verify the token. An in-memory table is not suitable anymore, unless it can be done inside the Gateway instance.

Does this has to be done programmatically (like now), or there is a configurable mechanism in Gateway or some other Azure service?

Comment: Why is the number of instances a concern? How do clients look like, user-agents? User-agents send in JWTs in cookies with every request. App Service comes with a load balancer (ARR), unless you need some fancy routing that Application Gateway is a 3rd wheel.

Comment: Hi @evilSnobu, the gateway is necessary for several reasons. We will have 2 or 3 kinds of app servers which are routed based on the url.

Comment: Have you considered implementing IdentityServer4?

Answer (score 2):

Application Gateway does not support authentication with AD. It also definitely does not support custom authentication. Hence the authentication and authorization has to be done at the backend servers. The solution would require a distributed cache where tokens are kept, which is accessible to all backend servers. You could use [Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/) for this.